# Odd Behaviour Updating UI From Within Task/Action Delegate

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm facing an odd issue with updating the UI from within a `Task`. The code below is taken from my `GetWorkingProxies` method which basically takes a number of proxies, pings them, and returns the working list.

I am using `Task.WhenAll` to create concurrency so it pings as many as possible at one time, rather than one at a time.

The problem is though, within the Action delegate I update the UI. Which is below:

```
Action<string> checkProxy = s => {
    Ping ping = new Ping();

    try {
        string[] proxy = s.Split(':');
        lblLog.Text = "Testing Proxy: " + proxy[0];
        PingReply reply = ping.Send(proxy[0], Convert.ToInt32(proxy[1]));

        if(reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
             workingProxies.Add(s);
             lblSuccessProxies.Text = workingProxies.Count.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
             failedProxies.Add(s);
             lblFailedProxies.Text = failedProxies.Count.ToString();
        }
    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // DEBUG
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
};
```

And here is the code that creates the `Task` array ...

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[proxies.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < proxies.Count; i++)
{
    string tmp = proxies[i];
    tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => checkProxy(tmp));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

What I can't understand is why `lblLog.Text = "Testing Proxy: " + proxy[0];` works fine, but `lblFailedProxies.Text = failedProxies.Count.ToString();` and `lblSuccessProxies.Text = workingProxies.Count.ToString();` both throw an `System.InvalidOperationException`.

I know from testing that it's a cross-thread issue, but how can one UI update work, but not the other from within the same Action delegate?

Why is this?

Edit:

The actual exception is:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in    System.Windows.Forms.dll
System.InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lblSuccessProxies' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_WindowText(String value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Text(String value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Label.set_Text(String value)
   at SoundCloudPlays.Form1.<>c__DisplayClass12.<getProxies>b__10(String s) in ...
```

Comment: Are you sure its not the line above that's throwing? Could you be iterating over those collections when you add to them?

Comment: If I comment out the `lblSuccessProxies` and `lblFailedProxies` I don't get the exceptions. As soon as I uncomment I get the exceptions.

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: Secondary guess, the "Count" property is performing an iteration and someone is getting in the middle of that and adding. Does it work if you lock around those add/UI updates?

Comment: What is the actual exception? Can you show us the message?

Comment: Updated question with actual exception.

Comment: There you go: " Control 'lblSuccessProxies' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on". Odd that lblLog.Text did work...

Comment: Yeah, this is why I'm confused. I understand the problem, but I don't know why lblLog.Text works fine.

Comment: I have a theory - confirming now.

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. I get cross-thread exceptions on `lblLog` (as expected). My theory could still be valid - but in your setup. Basically it revolved around the state machine that the compiler creates for `async/await` and the captured context at any given point in the code. Your code is obviously different to mine.. which is why its acting differently.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Ah possibly yes.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, I don't think that's related. The code that updates the UI is not using async/await, it's just a synchronous method started with Task.Run, so it runs in a new thread.

Comment: Just a hunch: Could it be that the text you set for lblLog.Text is the same text the label already has (before you run the task(s))? Because in that case the property setter bails out because of the same value being set without doing anything else (not even checking the thread context) - hence no exception there...

Comment: @elgonzo no. The text set to lblLog changes each time it checks a proxy.

Comment: Cross thread exceptions aren't predictable. There is stuff happening under the covers that you're probably not entirely aware of. Sometimes you get an exception, sometimes you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do a minimal change like below. Note the use of `await SendAsync()`, now continuations happen asynchronously on the UI thread, so it's safe to access the UI. Also, you no longer need to use `Task.Run`:

```
Func<string, Task> checkProxyAsync = async(s) => {
    Ping ping = new Ping();

    try {
        string[] proxy = s.Split(':');
        lblLog.Text = "Testing Proxy: " + proxy[0];
        PingReply reply = await ping.SendAsync(proxy[0], Convert.ToInt32(proxy[1]));

        if(reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
             workingProxies.Add(s);
             lblSuccessProxies.Text = workingProxies.Count.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
             failedProxies.Add(s);
             lblFailedProxies.Text = failedProxies.Count.ToString();
        }
    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // DEBUG
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
};
```

Use:

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[proxies.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < proxies.Count; i++)
{
    string tmp = proxies[i];
    tasks[i] = checkProxyAsync(tmp);
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: This solution appears to block the UI completely.

Comment: @JamesJeffery, are you using DNS names or IP addresses? It could be that that the DNS name resolution part of `SendAsync` is blocking. If so, try changing it like this: `PingReply reply = await Task.Run(() => ping.Send(proxy[0], Convert.ToInt32(proxy[1])));`

Comment: Or `PingReply reply = await Task.Run(async () => await ping.SendAsync(proxy[0], Convert.ToInt32(proxy[1])));`

Comment: @PauloMorgado, right, but I think it's something wrong with the OP's code elsewhere, because the Framework does already offload the DNS resolution to `ThreadPool`: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/NetworkInformation/ping.cs#2bad2f36f67c84e0

Comment: @Noseratio, I would expect it to do that, but hadn't checked. I was just offering an alternative on your comment. Although you sent the call to the `ThreadPool` it can still be async and free that thread instead of blocking.

Comment: @PauloMorgado, I agree. This might be a bit more neat: `await Task.Run(() => ping.SendAsync(proxy[0], Convert.ToInt32(proxy[1])))`. No extra `async/await` for the lambda, and it would still unwrap the inner task.